# Mathematica 9 Autocomplete Pop-up issue

Tags: textures, autocomplete

I've just installed Mathematica 9.0.1 Student Edition on my Laptop and my Home PC. 
On my Laptop, it works just fine. But on my Home PC I get this weird issue of the pop-up command autocomplete window having some weird graphical issues as seen in the attached picture. I've already tried resetting and reinstalling it. It didn't help. When I click on the arrow and scroll through the list, the whole thing goes black.

PC is running Windows 7 Ultimate (x64)
CPU: i7 870
GPU: Nvidia GTX-470 (Drivers are up-to-date)

Thanks, for your help!

[image: The described problem]

Comment: Sounds like you might want to contact support at wolfram.com about this issue.

Comment: yeah, contacted the Wolfram-Support. They weren't able to help either. The guy there told me it's probably a bug and he's going post a bug report.